# Get the most frequent value of a column and how frequently it occurs

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

My query concerns two tables on my app, `areas` and `happenings`. An area has many happenings with each happening having a `primary_area_id` foreign key. I'm trying to get the most frequent day that happenings take place in each area, and what proportion of the happenings in each area take place on that day.

My query currently can get the most popular day in each area but struggling with how to extend that to get the frequency. My current query:

```
SELECT a.location, mode() within group(order by(to_char(h.started_at, 'Day'))) as day
FROM areas a 
JOIN happenings h on a.id = h.primary_area_id
WHERE h.started_at between {{start}} and {{end}}
GROUP BY 1
```

Sample areas:

```
id | location   | active
-------------------------
1  | Wandsworth | active
2  | Bexley     | active
```

Sample happenings:

```
 id |          title           | primary_area_id |        started_at         |   type    
----+--------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+----------
  3 | Go for a run in the park |               1 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  5 | Go to a restaurant       |               1 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  4 | Go to the cinema         |               1 | Sun, 19 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  6 | Go to a restaurant       |               2 | Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  7 | Go to a club             |               2 | Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
```

So my query should return:

```
location  | most_frequent_day | percentage
-----------------------------------------
Wandsworth| Saturday          | 66.66%
Bexley    | Monday            | 100%
```

As 2 out of 3 happenings in Wandsworth took place on a Saturday and all (2 out of 2) happenings took place on a Monday in Bexley

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the data in your tables in text format?

Comment: @MichaelGrogan have added some samples - let me know if you'd prefer a different format

Answer (score 1):

As a means to answering this question, I created three more rows of hypothetical data to work with in each table:

**Areas table**

```
select * from areas;

 id | location | active 
----+----------+--------
  1 | Bexley   | true
  2 | Other    | true
  3 | Bexley   | true
  4 | Bexley   | true
(4 rows)
```

**Happenings table**

```
select * from happenings;

 id |          title           | primary_area_id |        started_at         |   type    
----+--------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+----------
  3 | Go for a run in the park |               1 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  5 | Go to a restaurant       |               3 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  4 | Go to the cinema         |               2 | Sun, 19 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
  6 | Go to a restaurant       |               4 | Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun
(4 rows)
```

The happenings table shows an abbreviation for each day, followed by the date and time. To simplify this problem somewhat, **ALTER TABLE** can be used to add a variable that contains the day only - which is the variable that one wishes to use when calculating the proportion for each day.

```
alter table happenings add day varchar(10);
```

Then, the new variable day can be updated using the LIKE clause as follows:

```
update happenings set day='Saturday' where started_at like 'Sat%';
update happenings set day='Sunday' where started_at like 'Sun%';
update happenings set day='Monday' where started_at like 'Mon%';
```

Here is a sample of the new table:

```
 id |          title           | primary_area_id |        started_at         |   type   |   day    
----+--------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+----------+----------
  3 | Go for a run in the park |               1 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun | Saturday
  5 | Go to a restaurant       |               3 | Sat, 18 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun | Saturday
  4 | Go to the cinema         |               2 | Sun, 19 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun | Sunday
  6 | Go to a restaurant       |               4 | Mon, 20 Feb 2023 10:00:00 | GroupRun | Monday
(4 rows)
```

Now, the proportions of each day by percentage for each location can be calculated using the **OVER** clause. For instance, if we want to know just the proportion of each days for the Bexley area, it can be done as follows:

```
select t1.location, day, count(*), count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() as percentage_days from areas as t1 inner join happenings as t2 on t1.id=t2.primary_area_id where location='Bexley' group by t1.location, t2.day;
```

The query returns:

```
 location |   day    | count |   percentage_days   
----------+----------+-------+---------------------
 Bexley   | Monday   |     1 | 33.3333333333333333
 Bexley   | Saturday |     2 | 66.6666666666666667
(2 rows)
```

Note that count is counting the number of days, i.e. there are two Saturday entries for Bexley and one Monday entry in this instance.

On the other hand, if we wish to simply identify the contribution of each day across all locations as a whole, then the WHERE clause can simply be removed.

```
select t1.location, day, count(*), count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() as percentage_days from areas as t1 inner join happenings as t2 on t1.id=t2.primary_area_id group by t1.location, t2.day;
```

In this case, the query returns:

```
location |   day    | count |   percentage_days   
----------+----------+-------+---------------------
 Bexley   | Monday   |     1 | 25.0000000000000000
 Bexley   | Saturday |     2 | 50.0000000000000000
 Other    | Sunday   |     1 | 25.0000000000000000
(3 rows)
```

Please also see the following [tutorial](https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1871-calculating-percentage-of-total-rows-in-sql) for further information.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a thorough answer. Unfortunately I don't think the resulting data is quite right. I'm looking to group the data by area, and then for each area find the most common day that a happening takes place, and what percentage of sessions happening in that area occur on that favourite day. Have updated the original question with clearer sample data and desired output.

Also `alter table` isn't an option - I can't alter the database structure for this query

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying. If using ```ALTER TABLE``` is not an option, then it might be possible to group by date instead. However, this would assume that all the timestamps across each date are the same, which may or may not be the case depending on your dataset.